# Asp.net MVC 5 Localized aware razor view engine

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm looking into doing some localization aware view engine.
I read some post and questions but all are quite old and related to mvc3 where mobile support wasn't introduced. Scott have a post on his blog about this and an implementation with some cache 'issues' as he described there.

My question is, since from mvc3 to mvc5 few thing changed regards to razor view engine, what would the preffered way to implement localized views ?

So if localization is `es-UY` it serves the page `Views/Index.es-UY.cshtml`.

Currently the framework do this for `Views/Index.mobile.cshtml`, I like to extend that logic if possible to account for localization instead of browser.

any guidance appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't aware the MVC 5 allowed the .mobile possibility, that seems interesting. A year or so ago I confronted the same problem of both themeing and localization for my MVC 4 projects. None of the hot shot articles out there addressed the issue.

So, I chose the best of the best from themeing and localization and merged it with other improvements made by me into the AspNetMvcThemeableViewEngine you can search. I believe I put it in CodePlex.

Anyway, I just updated the custom view engine project to MVC 5, Razor 3 but now it doesn't seem to be localizing. Have to figure it out which changes from MVC4 to 5 broke the engine.